# How can i find and install (acspid) python PID library

Tags: pid

How can i find and  install (acspid) python PID library in the folowing code

```
import acspid
pid=acspid.pidcont(1.2,0.02,0.01,5,-5)
```

Comment: Sorry I dont really know how to do that. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on github:  [ASC-PID](https://github.com/hoo2/toolbox)